# Not able to get JSONObject in to JSONArray IN JAVA eclipes

Tags: arrays, json, jsonobjectrequest

I was not able to get JsonObject while I try to covert JsonObject to JsonArray

JSON DATA:

```
{
    "in”: [
        {
            "Action": "In",
            "namespace": "Zdesk",
            "InDate": "Nov 4, 2019"
        },
        {
            "Action": "OUT",
            "namespace": "Zdesk",
            "InDate": "Nov 4, 2019"
        },
        {
            "Action": "In",
            "namespace": "Zdesk",
            "InDate": "Nov 4, 2019"
        }
    ],
    "click": [
        {
            "Action": "Click",
            "namespace": "Zdesk",
            "InDate": "Sep 27, 2019"
        },
        {
            "Action": "Click",
            "namespace": "Zdesk",
            "InDate": "Nov 4, 2019"
        },
        {
            "Action": "Click",
            "namespace": "Zdesk",
            "InDate": "Nov 4, 2019"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I use the below code to get those objects using the "Get" method

how to get "click" objects alone,

i tried below code

```
URL url = new URL("https://localdummy.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.connect();
```

and get those details in "inline"

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    inline+=sc.nextLine();
}

System.out.println(inline);

sc.close();
}
```

Then got those object into array

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject (inline);
JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("in");  //its working    
//JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("click");   <- <- <- <-//its not working . i need to use this ((((its issues))))
```

please help me to get jobj in to jsonarr_1 for get "click"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;

public class Demo{
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String resp = "{\"in\":[{\"Action\":\"In\",\"namespace\":\"Zdesk\",\"InDate\":\"Nov4,2019\"},{\"Action\":\"OUT\",\"namespace\":\"Zdesk\",\"InDate\":\"Nov4,2019\"},{\"Action\":\"In\",\"namespace\":\"Zdesk\",\"InDate\":\"Nov4,2019\"}],\"click\":[{\"Action\":\"Click\",\"namespace\":\"Zdesk\",\"InDate\":\"Sep27,2019\"},{\"Action\":\"Click\",\"namespace\":\"Zdesk\",\"InDate\":\"Nov4,2019\"},{\"Action\":\"Click\",\"namespace\":\"Zdesk\",\"InDate\":\"Nov4,2019\"}]}";
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parseObject(resp);
        JSONArray click = jsonObject.getJSONArray("click");
        System.out.println(click);

    }
}
```

you will get what you want:

`[{"Action":"Click","InDate":"Sep 27, 2019","namespace":"Zdesk"},{"Action":"Click","InDate":"Nov 4, 2019","namespace":"Zdesk"},{"Action":"Click","InDate":"Nov 4, 2019","namespace":"Zdesk"}]`

hope to help you

Comment: Thanks Huang, its more useful for me... its working